# Perl command line regex to modify all pattern matches

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, perl

I'm trying to use some arithmetic over the matched patterns in `perl` command line. I'm able to do it for one match but not for all.

```
str="a1b2c3"
perl -pe 's/\d+/$&+1/e'  <<<"$str"
a2b2c3
```

I understand `$&` refers to the first matched digit `1` here. What do I need to do to add `1` to all the digits? Is there a variable similar to `$&` that represents all matched patterns? or the regex needs to be modified to match multiple digits.

For the given input, I'm expecting output something like

```
a2b3c4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
str="a1b2c3"
perl -pe 's/\d+/$&+1/ge' <<<"$str"
```

The `g` flag to the substitution would make Perl apply the expression for each non-overlapping match on the input line.

Nitpick: There are actually no capture groups involved here (*the original question mentioned capture groups*).  The Perl variable `$&` is the "string matched by the last successful pattern match".  This is different from e.g. `$1` and `$2` etc. that refer to the string matched by the corresponding capture group (parenthesised expression). There are no capture groups in `\d+`, but you could have used `s/(\d+)/$1+1/ge` instead, which does use a single capture group.

There is no difference between `s/(\d+)/$1+1/ge` and `s/\d+/$&+1/ge` in terms of outcome.  In this short in-line Perl script, it makes no difference whether you choose to use one or the other, but generally you'd like to avoid using `$&` in longer Perl programs that do many regular expression operations, at least if using an older Perl release.

From `perldoc perlvar` (my emphasis):

> Performance issues
>
> Traditionally in Perl, any use of any of the three variables `` $` ``, `$&` or `$'`
>       (or their `use English` equivalents) anywhere in the code, **caused all
>       subsequent successful pattern matches to make a copy of the matched
>       string**, in case the code might subsequently access one of those variables.
>       This imposed a considerable performance penalty across the whole program,
>       so generally the use of these variables has been discouraged.
>
> [...]
>
> In Perl 5.20.0 a new copy-on-write system was enabled by default, **which
>       finally fixes all performance issues with these three variables**, and makes
>       them safe to use anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're actually using the `zsh` shell (`<<<` is a non-standard operator that does come from `zsh`, but has been copied to a few other shells since), note that you don't need to invoke `perl` for that.

You can do:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m) below
printf '%s\n' ${str//(#m)<->/$((MATCH+1))}
```

Where

- `(#m)` turns on the capturing of the whole match in `$MATCH` (the equivalent of `perl`'s `$&`)
- `<->`  matches any sequence of decimal digits (it's like `<5-12>` but without any bound).